# Singular and plural sentences

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

1. A large number of rare paintings **were** sold last year.
2. A large number of rare paintings **was** sold last year.

Which one of the sentences above is the correct one? If I consider that the verb to sell refers to 'a large number', then the use of 'was' is correct. However, considering that it refers to 'rare paintings' then I should use 'were', right?

How should I proceed on my reasoning?

Comment: Please see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are Mr. White's other 10th grade English class.
Our answer is:
a number vs. the number

The number of people we need to hire **is** thirteen.

A number of people **have** written in about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

We are Mr. White's 10th grade English class.
We feel that if the subject were rare paintings,then it would be plural.
However there is a faction among us that believes that the subject ia a large number.
Our split:
14=Rare paintings
3 = a large number
11 are too scared to answer